# how to make binding between a list to listbox in xaml?

Tags: wpf, list, xaml, binding, listbox

I have an `ObservableCollection` and a `ListBox`, I want to make binding between them, but without using `listBox1.DataSource/ItemsSource = ...` in behind code, I found a plenty of such examples, but I need to make binding only in xaml code
If i'm not mistaken, I need to make my list as a property first.

```
    private ObservableCollection<ProtectionBase> _listhelmets;
    public ObservableCollection<ProtectionBase> ListHelmets
    {
        get { return _listhelmets; }
        set { _listhelmets = value; }
    } 

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        ListHelmets.Add(new Helmet(){protection=5});
        ListHelmets.Add(new Helmet() { protection = 7 });

        this.DataContext = _listhelmets;
    }
```

xaml code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listhelmets" Height="215" Width="197"       PreviewMouseDown="helmet_MouseDown1"
                     PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="helmet_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                     PreviewMouseMove="helmet_PreviewMouseMove" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13" Background="Silver" Margin="0 0 0 10" Text="Шлемы"> </TextBlock>
                <ListBoxItem >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listhelmets, Path=SelectedItem}"
                         MouseEnter="ChoosingHelmet1"
                         DragOver="helmet1_DragOver"                                
                         DragEnter="helmet_DragEnter" AllowDrop ="true"
                         DragLeave="helmet_DragLeave" MouseLeftButtonDown="helmet_MouseLeftButtonDown_1">
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding protection, ElementName=ListHelmets[0]}" Width="124"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                         <Image Source="D:..."/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: right now u r doing binding in XAML only and not in code. and you can set `DataContext` in XAML too.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan then what should I write DataContext="{Binding ...}"?

Comment: `<Window.DataContext>
       <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/></Window.DataContext>` , and in your ListBox `ItemsSource="{Binding ListHelmets}"` .

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using MVVM do this in your code behind :

```
ListHelmets.Add(new ProtectionBase(){protection = 5});
ListHelmets.Add(new ProtectionBase() { protection = 7 });
listhelmets.ItemsSource = ListHelmets;
```

The textblock text *protection* must be a property in the class *ProtectionBase*

In the xaml do this :
Remove *ItemsSource="{Binding}"*,
Remove the Datacontext from stackpanel,
Remove *, ElementName=ListHelmets[0]*

If you are using MVVM let me know

Comment: do I need mvvm? i want to fill listbox with Helmets form ListHelmets, each Helmet has its own Property which I want to be shown in a texbox below, event - PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown.
for now I've written it for each listboxitem like this
   
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ListHelmets[1],      Path=Protection}"></TextBlock>
using different [i] in brackets, guess that's not right
@rohHit

Comment: You dont need MVVM. Do what I have told earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work:

xaml :

```html
 <ListBox x:Name="listhelmets" Height="215" Width="197" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13" Background="Silver" Margin="0 0 0 10" Text="Шлемы"></TextBlock>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding protection}" Width="124"/>
                </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>          
</ListBox>
```

xaml.cs

```
listhelmets.Items.Clear();
            List<ProtectionBase> Helmets = new List<ProtectionBase>();
            Helmets.Add(new ProtectionBase(){ protection = 7});
            Helmets.Add(new ProtectionBase() { protection = 8 });
            Helmets.Add(new ProtectionBase() { protection = 9 });

            listhelmets.ItemsSource = Helmets;
```

(I have removed all the events and unnecessary stuff from the xaml. Do add all the necessary events)

I dont understand the need for this textblock :

```html
<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13" Background="Silver" Margin="0 0 0 10" Text="Шлемы"></TextBlock>
```

I think you should put it above the listbox. You should not put it inside the ListBox